# FCM: invalid parameter, token reason for iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm integrating FCM into my iOS app. I'm receiving this error when sending token to my backend server:

Invalid parameter: Token Reason: iOS device tokens must be no more than 400 hexadecimal characters

And in my code, I'm sending FCM registration token to the server. Is this correct? or should I send device token instead? If so, what's the use of this FCM registration token for?

Need help on this.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
//Get FCM registration token
[[FIRInstanceID instanceID] instanceIDWithHandler:^(FIRInstanceIDResult * _Nullable result,
                                                    NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error fetching remote instance ID: %@", error);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Remote instance ID token: %@", result.token);

        [UserDefaultUtility setDeviceToken:result.token];
    }
}];

}

#pragma mark - FCM delegate
- (void)messaging:(FIRMessaging *)messaging didReceiveRegistrationToken:(NSString *)fcmToken {
// Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.

NSLog(@"FCM registration token: %@", fcmToken);
[UserDefaultUtility setDeviceToken:fcmToken];

}
```

I'm doing this on simulator, does it affect it?

Comment: What backend server are you sending this token to? Is it explicitly expecting an iOS token? The FCM registration token is firebase's token for your device and different from your actual device token.

Comment: @HirdayGupta the backend server is our own CMS backend server. Previously before using Firebase, app is sending the device token from didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken method. So I thought to send the FCM token using the same method. 

The device token is used to send targeted notification to certain user only. So app is sending the device token to server for server side to use to determine who to send notification to. That's from before using FCM. Now we want to use FCM for our push notification, so should send in the FCM token or device token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely an error with your backend.

The FCM Token is generated by Firebase, and Firebase alone handles the mappings between the FCM token and the iOS Device Token. Thus, when you use FCM, you only care about the FCM token so that is definitely what you should be sending. However, it seems that your backend, for some reason, is expecting an actual iOS Device token.

So to fix this error, you have to change your backend code (which you haven't provided so I can't help with), so that it is not expecting an actual iOS  Device Token, but instead expects an FCM token.

Then, to "use FCM", you'd change your backend to stop directly interacting with Apple's push notification servers (or whatever other service you currently used that needed the actual iOS Device Token), and start interacting with the FCM APIs instead, using any of the methods listed [in the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#choosing-a-server-option). The FCM APIs would use the FCM Token to identify which device to send push notifications to.